# プロパティグリッドのリスト選択肢(表示文字列)を変更する方法

Tags: c#

以下のクラスをPropatyGridのオブジェクトとして用いて、
リストボックスにx1、x2、x3が選択可能な表示状態になります。

この選択肢(x1、x2、x3)を実行中に動的に表示変更する方法はありますでしょうか。
(例えば、y1、y2,y3の表示に変更する。)

```
　　　　public class Apx8816_EepromProperty
　　　　{
　　　　　　　　public enum SELECT_VALUE
　　　　        {
        　　　　    x1 = 0,
      　　　　      x2 = 1,
           　　　　 x3 = 2
       　　　　 }

      　　　　  SELECT_VALUE _SelValue = 0;
      　　　　  [Category(" Parameter")]
       　　　　 [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
        　　　　[Description("Select Value.")]
       　　　　 public SELECT_VALUE SelSetValue
       　　　　 {
          　　　　  get { return _SelValue; }
           　　　　 set { _SelValue = (SELECT_VALUE)value; }
        　　　　}
　　　　}
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[PropertyGridコントロールの使い方 - DOBON.NET](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/propertygrid.html), [.NET Framework の PropertyGrid コントロールの高度な活用](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/msdn/architecture-center/cc440113(v=vs.71)), [.NET プロパティ ブラウザー Visual Studio使用してコンポーネントを本当に RAD にする](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302334(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: あと関係するか不明ですがこんな記事も。[General purpose dynamic list for a PropertyGrid in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66779911/9014308), [Can you/How to specify Editor at runtime for PropertyGrid (for PCL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46099675/9014308), [Is winform PropertyGrid able to edit dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31446787/9014308), [Change .NET Property Grid readonly attribute at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22060112/9014308), [How to modify PropertyGrid at runtime (add/remove property and dynamic types/enums)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313822/9014308)